# Current Open Position vs Currently Open Position

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I came across the context *Currently Open Position*, but I felt it was grammatically wrong. When I googled, I saw relatively equivalent context usage of both.

Which is the right thing to use here?

Answer (score 1):

Both *Current open position* and *currently open position* are grammatically correct.

*Current open position*: It is formed by 2 adjectives, *current* and *open*. It is definitely OK to use 2 adjectives to describe a noun.

*Currently open position*: It is formed by *position*, described by another relative clause, *currently open*. You can add adverbs before an adjective, as in this example, and you would be more convinced of this fact by looking at the sentence *position that is currently open*.

So to conclude, both are grammatically correct.

Well, for the problem of which of them is more commonly used or natural, I could not say anything useful, and I feel that they are equally frequently used.

I am not that good in English, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you are correct, but it would be interesting to explore the further question of whether they mean the same thing.

Comment: @SuperCool. +1 for good answer, but as said by Greg it would be interesting to explore further.